# apply blur on all inputs in a span angular4

Tags: javascript, html, angular

on my screen i am showing a few inputs like this.

```
<span>
<input #field (keyup.enter)="setName(item,field.value); newfolder = null" type="text" class="top-of-dom folder_name_text_box">
    <button class="top-of-dom" [ngClass]="{'active': item.folder_type=='category'}" (click)="item.folder_type='category'">single</button>
    <button class="top-of-dom" [ngClass]="{'active': item.folder_type=='label'}" (click)="item.folder_type='label'">multi</button>
    <i class="fa fa-check cursor-pointer top-of-dom" (click)="setName(item,field.value);" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-times cursor-pointer top-of-dom" (click)="deleteNode(item.id);"></i>
</span>
```

all i want to do is when the user losses focus and does not click the check r times icon. an event should be triggered.

In simple words if the user presses anything other than these five elements i want to call an event. I have tried to apply `(blur)="SomeMethod"` to the `span` above, but it is useless. And applying it on `input` tag simply calls the event even if the `i` in the same group is clicked

Answer (score 0):

Go for

```
(clickOutside)="something"
```

on span

check [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-click-outside)

Comment: and what if a user uses the tab key to move to next input?

Answer (score 0):

use

```
<span tabindex=0></span>
```

to ger focus on your span and then you can call blur method.

so basically the blur event fires when the focus is lost. By default, a div or span element cannot have the focus in the first place so it can't be lost.

here if you set tabindex on a span, then it can gain the focus and you call your function on blur. this also works with tab key press event.

for more check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/westonruter/UAWRc/)

Answer (score 0):

it is done in core js, not on angular but you can use the same logic in angular [refer](https://juristr.com/blog/2016/09/ng2-event-registration-document/), try this

```js
document.body.addEventListener("click", function() {
    var parents = [];
    var p = event.target;

    while (p !== document) {
        var o = p; 
        if(o.className.indexOf("input-items") !== -1) break;
        p = o.parentNode;
    }
    
    if(p === document) {
      // your code here
      console.log("here");
    }
})
```

```html
<body>
  <span class="input-items">
    <input #field (keyup.enter)="setName(item,field.value); newfolder = null" type="text" class="top-of-dom folder_name_text_box">
      <button class="top-of-dom" [ngClass]="{'active': item.folder_type=='category'}" (click)="item.folder_type='category'">single</button>
      <button class="top-of-dom" [ngClass]="{'active': item.folder_type=='label'}" (click)="item.folder_type='label'">multi</button>
      <i class="fa fa-check cursor-pointer top-of-dom" (click)="setName(item,field.value);" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      <i class="fa fa-times cursor-pointer top-of-dom" (click)="deleteNode(item.id);"></i>
  </span>
  <h1> click here </h1>
  <h1> click here </h1>
  <h1> click here </h1>
  <h1> click here </h1>
</body>
```